# Is there a way to just get the message author's name

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to say do like message.author.name or something, or a way to return the authors name and id?

Comment: Well, its [message.author.username](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User?scrollTo=username) and [message.author.id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User?scrollTo=id) - Or do i get your question wrong?

Comment: I was just giving an example of what might show the authors name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Message author's ID

Code: `message.author.id`

Returns a [Snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) of the message author's id.

#### Message author's name

Code: `message.author.username`

Returns a string of the message author's name.

#### Quick code example:

Let's say we have a guy named 'Jimmy#7465' with the id '189746913631797249'

```
client.on('message', message => {
  console.log(message.author.id); // Expected output: '189746913631797249'
  console.log(message.author.username); // Expected output: 'Jimmy'
  message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.author.username}! Your id is ${message.author.id}!`);
})
```